# Executing function calls sequentially

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to fetch user input everytime the user edits the textfield and search users according to the input. In the beginning of the search function, I remove the users array and perform the search. However, the function is called concurrently and it empties the array even before performing the search. This might result in duplicate data in the user array. Is there a way to serialize the whole function call? I looked through GCD documents and tried to implemented some methods, but it didn't work out.

This is the source code

```
 // handles editting movement of the search textfield
@objc func textIsChanging(){
    //need to serialize execution to avoid concurrency.
    // wait until previous call completes? 
    searchUsers()

}

// search user from database.
private func searchUsers(){
    // empty user array and reload table view
    removeUsers()
    if let searchText = searchField.text?.lowercased() {
        // search with starting index..
        Api.User.queryUsersWithStartText(withText: searchText) { (user) in
            if(CurrentUserInfo.uid != user.uid){
                self.users.append(user)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are clearing the users array and then making a request to find a single user. how can you get duplicates? you've got an empty array and only fetching one user

Comment: @chan be aware that the `serialization` tag is for questions about converting data structures to text (such as `JSONSerialization`), your question is about sequential execution of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DispatchGroup` to execute asynchronous functions sequentially. You need to ensure that the `enter()` and `leave()` calls on the `DispatchGroup` are balanced and if you do so, the code in `dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {...}` will only execute if there is currently block in the `DispatchGroup` and hence another block can safely be added. By calling `searchUsers()` from inside `dispatchGroup.notify`, you ensure that the function is only called once its previous call finished execution.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

@objc func textIsChanging(){
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        searchUsers()
    }
}

// search user from database.
private func searchUsers(){
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    // empty user array and reload table view
    removeUsers()
    if let searchText = searchField.text?.lowercased() {
        // search with starting index..
        Api.User.queryUsersWithStartText(withText: searchText) { (user) in
            if(CurrentUserInfo.uid != user.uid){
                self.users.append(user)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    } else {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```